# Calculate Comirva GaussianComponent Class' weight

Tags: java, audio, speech-recognition

I am writing an audio recognition program. How can I find double array's weights in Java? I am using [`comirva.audio.util.gmm.GaussianComponent`](http://www.cp.jku.at/people/schedl/research/development/comirva/releases/0.36/CoMIRVA/doc/comirva/audio/util/gmm/GaussianComponent.html). To create `GaussianComponent` object, I have to find the weights.

Comment: See also [`comirva.audio.util.gmm.GaussianMixture`](http://www.cp.jku.at/people/schedl/research/development/comirva/releases/0.36/CoMIRVA/doc/comirva/audio/util/gmm/GaussianMixture.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before creating a gmm you have to initialize it. so you'll use the kmeansClustering (you found it on comirva too,) and this will give you the weight, the mean, and the covariance of each cluster . . so a cluster represent a gaussian component
                              & god help u.

Comment: Thank you very much mehemmel bachir.